# Set a Location with accented chars with scselect on OSX

Tags: macos, networking, bash, terminal, scselect

I have a location named "Café en Madrid". If I try to set it with scselect on Terminal, the accented é is turned into gibberish and the command fails:

```
[kodai.fernando ~/Desktop] scselect "Café en Madrid"
Set "Caf√© en Madrid" not available.

Defined sets include: (* == current set)
   64E7FFFD-4F08-46AB-ADAF-0CF5BEC57169 (Café en Madrid)
 * E790486F-5BDE-44D7-8C1D-43940F1F551C (Sao Francisco)
   D98A096B-5D3E-4FA2-8F72-915EE50FEC5E (Automatic)
```

How can I fix this? No I don't want to remove the accented char.

Comment: try to use scselect 64E7FFFD-4F08-46AB-ADAF-0CF5BEC57169

Comment: @kamae It's a good suggestion, consider posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`scselect` [assumes its arguments is encoded as *Mac OS Roman*](http://opensource.apple.com/source/configd/configd-24.1/scselect.tproj/scselect.c) (search for `kCFStringEncodingMacRoman`), and Terminal is by default using *Unicode (UTF-8)*. Change it in the preferences:

[image]

---

```
$ scselect "Café en Madrid"
CurrentSet updated to C88601E1-7163-429A-BB0C-E304DB2E00F7 (Caf√© en Madrid)
```

Funnily enough, this breaks the output.

---

Consider reporting a bug to Apple.